# Prolog - make list

Tags: list, prolog

Given the argument `makelist(A,N,K,M,L) :-` , should expand ,and it should return true if `A,N,K,M,L>0` Integer numbers with `M>=2` and `L` list :

```
[A^N mod M , A^(N+1) mod M , A^(N+2) mod M , ... , A*(N+K) mod M]
```

Expected results :

```
| ?- makelist(10,2,1,10000,L).
L = [100,1000]
| ?- makelist(2,6,10,100,L).
L = [64,28,56,12,24,48,96,92,84,68,36]
| ?- makelist(12345678,3,8,100,L).
L = [52,56,68,4,12,36,8,24,72]
| ?- makelist(2,3000,5,7,L).
L = [1,2,4,1,2,4]
| ?- makelist(2,555000,5,17,L).
L = [1,2,4,8,16,15]
| ?- makelist(2,3000000,5,21,L).
L = [1,2,4,8,16,11]
| ?- makelist(142857,98765432,9,100,L).
L = [1,57,49,93,1,57,49,93,1,57]
```

i thought a starting would be implementing the `K` element of exponent `(N+K)` by taking the numbers from `0` to `K`

```
bet(N, M, K) :- N =< M, K = N.
bet(N, M, K) :- N < M, N1 is N+1, bet(N1, M, K).


makelist(A,N,K,M,L) :- bet(0,K,(N+K)),
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: what would be you thing a good start to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution for small exponents

A well known **property of modular exponentiation** estabilishes that:

*x*^*n* **mod** *m* = (*x* **mod** *m*)^*n* **mod** *m*

Thus, for large bases with small exponents, you can use the following code:

```
makelist(A, N, K, M, L) :-
    A>0, N>0, K>0, M>0,
    K1 is N + K,
    findall(X, (between(N,K1,E), X is (A mod M)^I mod M), L).
```

Here are some solutions found with this code:

```
?- makelist(10,2,1,10000,L).
L = [100, 1000].

?- makelist(2,6,10,100,L).
L = [64, 28, 56, 12, 24, 48, 96, 92, 84|...].

?- makelist(12345678,3,8,100,L).
L = [52, 56, 68, 4, 12, 36, 8, 24, 72].

?- makelist(2,3000,5,7,L).
L = [1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4].

?- makelist(2,555000,5,17,L).
L = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 15].

?- makelist(2,3000000,5,21,L).
L = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 11].
```

Note that, without using such property, we cannot compute the answer for large bases with large exponents:

```
?- X is 142857^98765432 mod 100.
ERROR: Stack limit (0.5Gb) exceeded

?- X is (142857 mod 100)^98765432 mod 100.
X = 1.
```

#### Solution for large exponents

However, for large exponents, this code turns out to be **very inefficient**. For example:

```
?- time(makelist(142857,98765432,9,100,L)).
% 47 inferences, 115.328 CPU in -544348879559065600.000 seconds (?% CPU, 0 Lips)
L = [1, 57, 49, 93, 1, 57, 49, 93, 1|...].
```

So, a best approach for a large exponent *n* is to use the following definition:

- if *n* = 0, then *x*^*n* = 1
- else if *n* = 1, then *x*^*n* = *x*
- else if *n* is even, then *x*^*n* = (*x*^2)^(*n*/2)
- else if *n* is odd, then *x*^*n* = x*(*x*^2)^floor(*n*/2)

With this definition, we can compute *x*^*n* by using only O(lg *n*) multiplications. Based on it, we can define the following predicates:

```
fast_pow(X, N, M, P) :-
    (   N < 32
    ->  P is (X mod M)^N mod M
    ;   (   X1 is (X mod M)^2 mod M,
            N1 is N//2,
            fast_pow(X1, N1, M, P1),
            (   N mod 2 =:= 0
            ->  P is P1
            ;   P is (X mod M)*P1  mod M ) ) ).

fast_makelist(A, N, K, M, L) :-
    A>0, N>0, K>0, M>0,
    K1 is N + K,
    findall(P, (between(N,K1,E), fast_pow(A,E,M,P)), L).
```

Now, we have:

```
?- time(fast_makelist(142857,98765432,9,100,L)).
% 1,704 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
L = [1, 57, 49, 93, 1, 57, 49, 93, 1|...].
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the following code:

```
makelist(A,N,0,M,[X]) :- X is mod(A^N,M).
makelist(A,N,K,M,[X|L]) :-  
        Max is N + K,
        N <  Max,
        N1 is  N + 1,
        K1 is K-1,
        X is mod(A^N, M),
        makelist(A, N1, K1, M, L).
```

And then apply more constraints such as `M>= 2`.

Comment: is is possible to make it with the original argument `makelist(A,N,K,M,L)`  ?

Comment: @DavidDunn and what is the original argument?

Comment: `makelist(A,N,K,M,L) :-` expand from that here

Comment: @DavidDunn you can call this query `?- makelist(A,N,K,M,L)` and there is not any problem with that. for example `makelist(2,3,4,5,L).`

Comment: oh , i meant for the declaration like instead of `makelist(A,N,K,M,[X|L]) :-` to have `makelist(A,N,K,M,L) :-`

Comment: @DavidDunn if you dont'like `[X|L]` yust relpace it with `L` and in the body do `L = [H|T]` but this does not has much sense...